# Como faço para deixar scroll absoluto ao div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Queria deixar o scroll absoluto ao `div`, conforme fazem nas páginas de post do [site Mega Curioso](http://www.megacurioso.com.br/universo/74143-conheca-o-mapa-que-vai-lhe-dar-uma-nocao-melhor-sobre-o-tamanho-do-universo.htm), na barra esquerda onde tem as indicações de outras matérias.

Fucei no código fonte dos caras, mas não encontrei nenhum `Javascript` ou plugin que estivesse fazendo esse serviço, ou até mesmo um `CSS`.

Alguém pode me ajudar a como fazer isso?

Comment: Isso parece-me simplesmente uma `div` com altura defenida, conteúdo maior que altura e `overflow-y: scroll;`. Nada de JavaScript. Dá uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/yrLea844/ <-- é isso que procuravas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Primeiro você tem que definir uma altura fixa para a área de conteúdo.
2. Utilize `overflow: auto` para a área que você deseja que tenha a barra de scroll vertical.
3. Utilize `overflow: hidden` e `position: absolute` para a barra da esquerda não se mover.
4. Para que a barra de rolagem apareça no painel esquerdo somente quando o usuário coloca o cursor do mouse sobre ele utilize `:hover { overflow-y: scroll }`.

Coloquei abaixo o código do [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejYj6/) dado em [uma resposta para uma pergunta semelhante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954329/1639385) a essa em inglês.

```css
body {   
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: Calibri, Georgia, Ubuntu-C;  
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 20PX
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 139px;
    background: RED;   
}


#left_side{
    width: 210px;
    height: 300px;
    background:#119900;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    overflow:hidden; 
    position:absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left_side:hover { 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content{
     height: 250px;
    overflow:auto;
     padding: 20px;
     margin-left: 230px;
     margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background:ORANGE;
 }
```

```html
<div id="header">

</div>

<div id="left_side"> 
  a<br />b<br />c<br />d<br />e<br />f<br />g<br />h<br />i<br />j<br />k<br />a<br />b<br />c<br />d<br />e<br />f<br />g<br />h<br />i<br />j<br />k<br />a<br />b<br />c<br />d<br />e<br />f<br />g<br />h<br />i<br />j<br />k<br />a<br />b<br />c<br />d<br />e<br />f<br />g<br />h<br />i<br />j<br />k<br />a<br />b<br />c<br />d<br />e<br />f<br />g<br />h<br />i<br />j<br />k<br />a<br />b<br />c<br />d<br />e<br />f<br />g<br />h<br />i<br />j<br />k<br />
</div>

<div id="content">
    a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, legal! isso já ajudou bastante!
Mas teria alguma forma de desabilitar o scroll da body, igual eles fazer no mega curioso, quando o mouse está sobre a div da esquerda?

Comment: Pelo q eu percebi ele não usam css nesse processo, tipo um overflow:hidden.

Comment: Eu estou usando um função Jquery:

  `$('#left_side').mouseenter(function() {
   $('body').on('mousewheel', function(event, delta){
    console.log("false");
    return false;
   });
   $(this).css('overflow','auto');
  }).mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).css('overflow','hidden');
   $('.body').on('mousewheel', function(event, delta){
    console.log("true");
    return true;
   });
  });`

Comment: Mas ela tira o scroll de todos os elementos da página

Comment: Acho que agora consegui o efeito que você queria, @PedllR. Execute meu código novamente e você verá que o painel da esquerda apresenta a barra de rolagem somente quando o usuário coloca o mouse sobre ele.

Comment: Muito boa soluçao